# Error while testing file uploads in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, tdd

I am trying to add a profile image feature in my app. I am using the TDD approach to do this. The test for uploading profile picture shows green. But when I run the test to update the profile picture, it gives an error. Below is the code:

Controller:

```
public function store(StoreAvatarRequest $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');

    BasicInformation::updateOrCreate([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    ], [
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'avatar' => $path,
    ]);

    $this->showAlerts('alert-success', 'Profile Image uploaded successfully');

    return redirect()->route('avatar.index');

}

public function update(StoreAvatarRequest $request, $id)
{
    $basicProfile = BasicInformation::find($id)->first();
    $oldAvatarPath = $basicProfile->avatar;

    if ($basicProfile->user_id == auth()->id()) {
        $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');

        $basicProfile->avatar = $path;
        $basicProfile->update();

        Storage::delete($oldAvatarPath);
        $this->showAlerts('alert-success', 'Profile Image Updated Successfully');

        return redirect()->route('avatar.index');
    } else {
        // TODO :: Need to add logic here
    }
}
```

Test Case:

```
public function can_update_profile_picture()
{
    $this->actingAs($this->lawyer)->post(route('avatar.store'), [
        'avatar' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg', 600, 600)
    ]);

    $oldImagePath = $this->lawyer->information->avatar;

    $this->actingAs($this->lawyer)->put(route('avatar.update', ['id' => $this->lawyer->information->id]), [
        'avatar' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar1.jpg', 600, 600)
    ])
        ->assertRedirect(route('avatar.index'))
        ->assertSessionHas('status', 'Profile Image Updated Successfully');

    Storage::disk('local')->assertExists($this->lawyer->information->avatar);
    Storage::disk('local')->assertMissing($oldImagePath);
}
```

I am getting the following error when I run the test:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 
1 (100%)

Time: 298 ms, Memory: 20.00MB

There was 1 failure:
1) Tests\Feature\Dashboard\Lawyer\Account\ProfileImageTest::can_update_profile_picture
Unable to find a file at path [local/c5tjUUQDzU4iKHauJK68Z801I5iaYJ7e3cVQ5iA1.jpeg].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Comment: i think your old avatar need to be `$oldImagePath = $this->lawyer->avatar` not `$this->lawyer->information->avatar`

Comment: @AmrAly That was debugging typo. I have corrected it. But i am getting the same error. Also for both assertions (assertMissing & assertExists) i am getting the error. "Unable to find a file at path",

Comment: Also avatar column in defined in the BasicInformation Model and hasOne relationship with the User Model. So i am referencing the $oldImagePath using $this->lawyer->information->avatar

Comment: have u tried to use the file name instead like `assertExists('avatar1.jpg');` and `assertMissing('avatar.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of configuration and then preference for using store() or storeAs() methods.

First off you have to configure `filesystems.php`to recognize your tests Storage disk as the `fake()` disk:

```
'testing' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('framework/testing/disks/'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
```

Using that setup allows you to use your `APP_ENV` value in `phpunit.xml`for defaulting this disk for your tests.

Also, I use the use the `storeAs()`in my controller so that I can test against the filename I stored in the `assertExists()` method in my test.

```
$request->file('avatar')->storeAs('avatar', $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName())

Storage::disk('avatar')->assertExists('avatar.jpg');
```

This is what works for me and the files are deleted before running each test and clean up is not an issue.  You can also do a test for the hashName and use the store() method by getting the responsed and using `baseName()` to get the name of the new file.

Comment: I was able to figure out this issue using similar approach.

First i initialised fake storage disk using the following line of code  
`Storage::fake('public');`  

Then i am sending the fake file in a post request using the following line of code.  

`$fakeImage = UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg', 600, 600),`  

Then i am asserting if the file exists using the following line of code.  

`Storage::disk('public')->assertExists($fakeImage);`

Comment: @PawanKumar - Where is your controller writing the file?  If your controller writes this to `disk('public')` then this works for you, but not for the reason why you think it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have added to `phpunit.xml` next line:

```
<env name="FILESYSTEM_DRIVER" value="uploads"/>
```

and while checking

```
$image = $response->original['logo'];  // as the image name get changed in Controller
Storage::disk('uploads')->assertExists("public/uploads/$image");
```

Others codes are similar as [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#storage-fake).
You may Like to check the discussion at [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/changing-default-disk-for-testing).